# jquery ui drop helper

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

Using jQuery and Jquery UI, I have a draggable and droppable area, the draggable item has the following helper

```
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    grid: [ 20,20 ],
    cursorAt: { top: -12, left: -20 },
    helper: function(event) {
      return $('<div class="helper"></div>');
    }
  });
```

How do I get the helper to be `added` to the droppable area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit more investigation and another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660127) I have worked this out.

The in the `drop` event on the droppable element you need to clone the helper as you cannot drop the actual helper that shows during dragging.

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var newDiv = $(ui.helper).clone(false)
      .removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging')
      .css({position:'absolute', left:0, top:ui.offset.top - 12});
    $(this).append(newDiv);
  }
});
```

Thanks also to [Jason Benson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495280).

Alan

Answer (score 0):

in the helper function use

```
$(this).append('<div>somecontent</div>');
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. My understanding of the helper function was that it creates the HTML to be used as the helper. I would like that helper to remain visible if it is dropped onto a droppable area. Thanks for your answer