# how do i change a draggable object in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have a list of objects that once a user clicks on i would like to change-

my code is

```
$(function() {

        $( ".ui-state-default" ).draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            zIndex: 2700
```

and the draggable item is this- (it has some css styling which i would want to change as well)

```
<li class="ui-state-default"><a href="#">North Right</a></li>
```

I would like to change the whole li to just an icon instead of the text and everything. reason being that im dragging items onto a map and having the text would hide certain parts

Comment: Have you seen the [Draggable demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback)? I assume you want something like the "custom helper"?

Comment: i have seen people using $(ui.draggable).attr('src','/path/to/different/image'); to update an image but i was think i would need to update the whole html being dragged. im not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Dcb3/1/)?

I adapted the *clone helper* answer from [Can't drop jquery ui helper on droppable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660127/cant-drop-jquery-ui-helper-on-droppable/4662314#4662314)

Comment: perfect, i was siting playing with this and getting nowhere- $(ui.helper).text("x");
    $(ui.helper).addClass("ui-draggable-helper");